# Using $scope.$watch when using `this` scope in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller in my Angular app:

```
(function (angular) {
    function MyController() {
        this.name = 'Dave';

        // I want to have code like this:
        /*
          $scope.$watch('name', function (newValue, oldValue) {
              console.log(oldValue, "changed to", newValue);
          });
        */
    }

    window.myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('MyController', [MyController]);
})(angular);
```

Is there a way to use the features of `$scope.$watch` when attaching values to the `MyController` prototype?

I did notice that in my code, if I add something like `ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl"`, and change my `$scope.$watch` statement to `$scope.$watch('myCtrl.name', ...)`, it'll work after I add the `$scope` dependency, but that feels like tying my controller to my views, which feels wrong.

**Edit**

To attempt to clarify on what I'm asking. My HTML is something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.name" />
    <p>{{myCtrl.helloMessage}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller is something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    this.name = 'World';
    this.helloMessage = "Hello, " + this.name;

    var self = this;
    $scope.$watch('myCtrl.name', function () {
      self.helloMessage = "Hello, " + self.name;
    });
  }]);
```

That currently works, but as you can see, in the `$watch` call, I have to reference my controller by the `controllerAs` name from my view, which is less than ideal.

I've setup an example on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CpC8gxNnNZcj1jeEkhG7?p=preview)

Comment: What is the benefit of storing values on controller instances instead of scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### $watch

> Expression that is evaluated on each $digest cycle. A change in the return value triggers a call to the listener. Watch expression can be a sting or function.
>
> - string: Evaluated as expression
> - function(scope): called with current scope as a parameter.

### example

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.name = 'World'
  this.helloMsg = ''
  
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return this.name
  }.bind(this), function(newName) {
    this.helloMsg = "Hello, " + newName
  }.bind(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='MainCtrl as ctrl'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='ctrl.name' />
    {{ ctrl.helloMsg }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I thought that when using `$scope`, you can't use `this` scoped variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid being bound to the view by using `angular.bind` in your watch, i.e.

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
    self.helloMessage = "Hello, " + self.name;
}));
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I believe the $scope is automatically injected by angular.

Here's an example of a controller being declared:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Notice how $scope dependency is declared `'$scope'` and injected `function($scope)`

In other words, should yours look something like this ?

```
function MyController($scope) {}

window.myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController($scope)]);
```

EDIT:

I understand now. I've never had a need to use "controller as" but why not do it like this ?

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <p>{{helloMessage}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    this.name = 'World';
    this.helloMessage = "Hello, " + this.name;

    var self = this;
    $scope.$watch('name', function () {
      self.helloMessage = "Hello, " + self.name;
    });
  }])
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I can use the `$scope` dependency to hold my values, but I was hoping for a way to still be able to use the controllerAs style approach in my views, which it seems you can't do when using `$scope`

Comment: Well I'm really not sure about your "way" but bottom line, $scope has to be declared and injected.

Comment: I've added further explanation and an example above.